# Apache Nifi: Row to columnar data enrichment

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache Nifi as my ETL processor. But after looking into so many articles figured out there is no out of the box JOIN processor for SQL tables (or flowfile)

I have normalized data in below format. But I want to make it denormalized

| student_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake |
| 2 | Sean |

| student_id | subject | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SUB01 | 30 |
| 1 | SUB02 | 40 |
| 1 | SUB03 | 50 |
| 2 | SUB01 | 60 |
| 2 | SUB02 | 70 |
| 2 | SUB03 | 80 |

The expected final output is

| student_id | name | sub01 | sub02 | sub03 | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jake | 30 | 40 | 50 | 120 |
| 2 | Sean | 60 | 70 | 80 | 210 |

This has been too difficult to do with lookup service as I have to join with 2 keys which is not possible.

Has anyone solved this?

PS: The tables are transactional, the data keeps increasing over minutes.

Comment: Why do you need to do the JOIN inside NiFi? Have NiFi execute the JOIN query against the DB with something like ExecuteSQLRecord and get a flowfile with the joined results

Comment: It's not static data. It's a streaming data. The above one is an example of transformation required.

Comment: @Jake We will need more info for clarity on what system the data is coming from, how you're bringing it into NiFi....Your post and comment contradict each other and don't provide enough to go on...

Comment: @Jake either consider writing your own processor or use tools like Apache Flink who are better suited for merging/denormalizing/enriching unbounded streams with another. Don't expect magic from the stock NiFi processors.

How do you have these SQL tables in FlowFile while the data is streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Denormalizing a table in a flowing environment like NiFi may not be the solution you want. Imagine FlowFiles that look like the above with 10 million rows, denormalizing that in memory (or even on disk) in a flow environment would likely cause errors, backpressure, etc. IMO you're better off getting the source data into a target database and doing the denormalization there.

Having said that, for small FlowFiles it is feasible so feel free to write up a New Feature [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI) to add such a capability. Please include as many details as possible so the requirements are well-understood.

Comment: There are always the scripting processors, but then you're writing all the code yourself.